# Python error when adding values from one list of dictionaries to another unequal list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I have one list of dictionaries set up like this (but with ~11000 dicts inside, all with the same keys)

`kept = [{'date': 20150409, 'vel': 62.1, 'H_beg': 110.1},
         {'date': 20150409, 'vel': 39.5,....}]`

Now, I have another list `kept2[]` with some of the same keys that should match up with the values of the keys in `kept[]` but with an additional key `'log_10_m'` that I want to add to each dictionary in `kept[]` if the values of the keys `'vel'`, `'date'` and `'H_beg'` are the same for that dictionary within the list.

This doesn't seem that elusive, but when I try to print out a list displaying all values with key `'log_10_m'` in `kept[]` which should have just been added to each dictionary within it, it's saying `KeyError: 'log_10_m'`.

Can anyone tell me why the following code isn't working and if possible a faster way to do it because its taking a couple minutes each time I try it.

```
kept = [{'date': 20150409, 'vel': 62.1, 'H_beg': 110.1},
        {'date': 20150409, 'vel': 39.5,....}]

def compare():
    for row in kept:
        for row2 in kept2:
            if (row['date'] == row2['date'] and
                row['vel'] == row2['vel'] and
                row['H_beg'] == row2['H_beg'] and
                row['H_end'] == row2['H_end']):
                    row['log_10_m'] = row2['log_10_m']
                    break
            else:
                continue

    mass = [row3['log_10_m'] for row3 in kept]
    print '\n'
    print 'mass in kept:'
    print mass
```

Comment: It's possible there are no matches in `kept2` so `'log_10_m'` never gets added to that row in `kept`.

Comment: No I can see the data; all 11000 points should be adding except for 16 anomalies. (This is why I'm writing this function.)

Comment: The anomaly is probably the problem. Try `mass = [row3['log_10_m'] for row3 in kept if 'log_10_m' in row3]`